# Routing Error with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I believe it is a simple mistake but I have spent a lot of time thinking about it.

JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({              
            // Functionality
            slide_interval : 3000,// Length between transitions
                transition : 1, // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : 'image/4.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'image/1.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'image/2.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'image/3.jpg'}
                                            ]

            });
        });

        </script>
```

Error I got:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/image/4.jpg"):
```

and so on for the rest of the images

Could you please tell me what is the proper way to route to the correct directory?

Image folder is under public

Comment: If you are not sure, you can pass absolute image path instead of relative path.

Comment: absolute path gives me the same error. Earlier i just had a .html file and images in the same folder. Everything worked fine then. I got errors after i tried to include the html file as .html.erb and put images in public/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If images are located in public/images then you had a minor error in the path. Change image/4.png etc to images/4.png or /images/4.png in the javascript code.